# Puzzling fact about advection/convection diffusion equation in one dimension

Tags: dirac-delta, boundary-value-problem, linear-pde

Consider the PDE 
$$c_t + u c_x - Dc_{xx} = 0$$
If I consider a semi-infinite domain $0 < x < \infty$
with the following boundary conditions
$$c(0,t) = M\delta(t),  c(\infty, t) = 0$$
and initial condition $$c(x,0) = 0,$$ there is an exact solution

I got this by taxing a Laplace transform in time to get
$$s\hat{c} + u\hat{c}_x -D\hat{c}_{xx} = 0$$ subject to $\hat{c}(x=0) = M, \hat{c}(x = \infty) = 0$. Solving this we get
$\hat{c} = M \exp{((u-\sqrt{u^2+4sD})/2D)}$ which after inversion gives 
$$ c = \frac{M x}{\sqrt{4\pi D t^3}} \exp{\left(-\frac{(x-ut)^2}{4Dt}\right)}$$
However if I change the initial and boundary conditions to
$$c(0,t) = 0,  c(\infty, t) = 0$$
and $$c(x,0) = M\delta(x),$$ am stuck.

Physically, it seems to me both PDEs are describing the same physical process -- that of a pulse injection at the instant $t=0$ at the location $x=0$.

Then why am I unable to solve the second equation for an exact solution if I follow the same technique of Laplace transforms that enabled me to solve the first one ?

Comment: You can convert between such things (i.e. turn boundary conditions and initial data into forcing) using Duhamel's principle (which is a consequence of linearity). That said I don't see why the second case is so much more difficult, are you using temporal Laplace transforms or spatial?

Comment: @Ian: I used the temporal Laplace transform and then wrote down the solution to the spatial ODE directly.  In the second case, after I take a LT in time, I am stuck with the spatial second order ODE which has a dirac-delta term and two boundary conditions. Could you show me how the solution is obtained in this case ?

Comment: Upon temporal Laplace transforms you have $s\hat{c}(s,x)-c(0,x)+u\hat{c}_x(s,x)-D\hat{c}_{xx}(s,x)=0$. So $s \hat{c}(s,x)+u\hat{c}_x(s,x)-D\hat{c}_{xx}(s,x)=M\delta(x)$. Find the general solution to this spatial ODE and then plug in the BCs (either on the LT side, using the initial and final value theorems, or after inversion).

Comment: This is exactly the problem I have. I know the complementary function to solve the spatial ODE but I do not understand how to get the particular integral for the dirac-delta term. If you could show me that bit, it will be enough.

Comment: I understand that am basically looking for the Greens function of the spatial ODE, but I am not able to derive it.

Comment: @Ian: Yes, I realize that. I tried to go through the derivation of Greens function and use all the conditions for continuity, jump etc but it does not lead to anything sensible. Could you post an explicit expression  for it as an answer  to my question ?

Answer (score 0):

You have the spatial ODE

$$s\hat{c}(s,x)+u\hat{c}_x(s,x)-D\hat{c}_{xx}(s,x)=M\delta(x).$$

This is a second order linear ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients. The solution, for any fixed $s$, is the particular solution satisfying $\hat{c}(s,0)=0,\hat{c}_x(s,0)=M$. This is given by $\frac{M}{\lambda_2 - \lambda_1}(e^{\lambda_2 x}-e^{\lambda_1 x})$ where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are the roots of $-D\lambda^2+u\lambda+s=0$. (Note that $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ depend on $s$.) If these are in fact the same i.e. $u^2+4Ds=0$, then that ratio should be understood as a limit as $\lambda_1 \to \lambda_2$. (Physically this should never happen, since $u$ should be real, $D$ should be positive, and $s$ should have positive real part.) The solution to the original problem is then the inverse Laplace transform of this.

Comment: This is precisely the result I got. If both PDEs are going to give me the same  solution (they differ in whether I have a delta(t) or delta(x), I must get the same expression before the inverse LT. Notice that in the first PDE, taking LT and solving the bvp leads to a different expression. (It will give $M e^{\lambda_1 x}$ only. So there is a difference isnt it ? So I am back to my original question -- why doesnt this give the same solution though physically they appear to be the same ?

Comment: @me10240 Why would it give $Me^{\lambda_1 x}$ only? Can you write out your calculation? I suspect you have some error. These two are the same as you can see without reference to physics, using just Duhamel's principle.

Comment: I added the steps to explain.

Comment: @me10240 Hmm...I think one or the other is getting interpreted wrong, because in one case you have $\hat{c}(s,0)$ picking up the contribution, in the other you have $\hat{c}_x(s,0)$ picking up the contribution. At any rate, I'm also not sure why you're using delta functions necessarily at all. It seems that what you want to say is that $c(0,0)=M$ and $c(0,t)=0$ for $t>0$.

Comment: I was hoping to discover I am wrong and that the two problems do have the same solution.  But I do not have a choice other than delta function. I want to represent a pulse injection at an instant. Its either $\delta(t)$  at a boundary or $\delta(x)$ as an initial state.